# Windows 7 IIS is slow proportional to WAMP(Apachi)

Tags: php, mysql, apache, iis, server

I have a 32 bit Windows 7 machine and I want to use it as a server and run my PHP website on it and it all other clients will be able to use this website .
 for this I installed Windows IIS and I installed php5.5.12 and MySQL 5.5 and PHPmyAdmin on my PC and after that I put my side in this  path :

```
 C:\inetpub\wwwroot
```

and it works good and when other clients entere  this server IP they can access to this site and it works .
 but my problem is this that  server is really slow  proportional to (Wamp) Apache for example , I run this exactly site on this exactly Windows machine, with WAMP (which use Apache) and it's really faster  than the IIS.

for example when I want to load a simple php page with Apache it takes less than a second , while when I want to load this exactly page on IIS it takes more than 5-6 seconds while the CPU and RAM usage is  Andra 50%, you know I have searched in Internet and I found that some other people has this issue, but I didn't find any good answer for resolve this issue .this is the way thath II do :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3HWS_u_k8KA

I don't know what shall I do ?  please give me an exact solution because I have searched on the internet and I have not found any good solution for it

**UPDATE**

finally I understood that it's probably browser caching problem, because in `Apachi`  web server I use the `.htaccess` file to cash all `CSS` and `Javascript` and `images`  in browser and after the first time, the website does not load these files again , so it loads  really fast fast but in `IIS` server `.htaccess` file does not work , now I don't know how the cash `CSS` and `Js`  &  `image` files in browser? I know I must use a web.congig but I don't know how to cash ?

Comment: I have used IIS in my production server handling 3,000 to 4,000 users per minutes without any problem. (I am running it on Windows Server 2008 RS2). Please show us how did you config your IIS to work with PHP?

Comment: Im using windows 7  32 bit , Ok Im recording  , Ill put the youtube link

Comment: @invisal here is  my way to create the serrver https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3HWS_u_k8KA